# Sum of rows based on column values with factors

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe;

```
Fruit <- c("orange", "orange", "apple", "pineapple", "lemon", "apple", "orange") 

Name <- c("julius", "julius", "john", "mary", "kathy", "john", "julius")

df <- data.frame(Fruit, Name);df
```

My aim is to have the sum of all the number of fruits eaten by each person so as to have the following table in the end;

```
         orange apple    pineapple  lemon
julius    2      1      
john             2      
mary                        1   
kathy     1                           1
```

I was trying out the aggregate function, but could only manage to have it output the total number of Fruits eaten by each person as follows;

```
df2 <- aggregate(Fruit~Name,df,length); df2
```

The output being;

```
    Name Fruit
1   john     2
2 julius     3
3  kathy     1
4   mary     1
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, Name~Fruit)
    Name apple lemon orange pineapple
1   john     2     0      0         0
2 julius     0     0      3         0
3  kathy     0     1      0         0
4   mary     0     0      0         1
```

Option 2

```
table(df)
# as pointed out by lebatsnok, the general command would be with(df, table(Fruit, Name))
           Name
Fruit       john julius kathy mary
  apple        2      0     0    0
  lemon        0      0     1    0
  orange       0      3     0    0
  pineapple    0      0     0    1
```

Comment: Thanks @Codoremifa. You made it so simple. I used the 2nd option though since the first throws the following error "package ‘dcast’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)"

Comment: `table(df)` works in this case because you don't have any other variables in the data frame. As a general case, `with(df, table(Fruit, Name))` is better.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want a simple two-way frequency table:

```
table(Fruit, Name)
#           Name
#Fruit       john julius kathy mary
#  apple        2      0     0    0
#  lemon        0      0     1    0
#  orange       0      3     0    0
#  pineapple    0      0     0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> library(gmodels)
> 
> CrossTable(Fruit, Name)


   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
| Chi-square contribution |
|           N / Row Total |
|           N / Col Total |
|         N / Table Total |
|-------------------------|


Total Observations in Table:  7 


             | Name 
       Fruit |      john |    julius |     kathy |      mary | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
       apple |         2 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         2 | 
             |     3.571 |     0.857 |     0.286 |     0.286 |           | 
             |     1.000 |     0.000 |     0.000 |     0.000 |     0.286 | 
             |     1.000 |     0.000 |     0.000 |     0.000 |           | 
             |     0.286 |     0.000 |     0.000 |     0.000 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
       lemon |         0 |         0 |         1 |         0 |         1 | 
             |     0.286 |     0.429 |     5.143 |     0.143 |           | 
             |     0.000 |     0.000 |     1.000 |     0.000 |     0.143 | 
             |     0.000 |     0.000 |     1.000 |     0.000 |           | 
             |     0.000 |     0.000 |     0.143 |     0.000 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
      orange |         0 |         3 |         0 |         0 |         3 | 
             |     0.857 |     2.286 |     0.429 |     0.429 |           | 
             |     0.000 |     1.000 |     0.000 |     0.000 |     0.429 | 
             |     0.000 |     1.000 |     0.000 |     0.000 |           | 
             |     0.000 |     0.429 |     0.000 |     0.000 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
   pineapple |         0 |         0 |         0 |         1 |         1 | 
             |     0.286 |     0.429 |     0.143 |     5.143 |           | 
             |     0.000 |     0.000 |     0.000 |     1.000 |     0.143 | 
             |     0.000 |     0.000 |     0.000 |     1.000 |           | 
             |     0.000 |     0.000 |     0.000 |     0.143 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |         2 |         3 |         1 |         1 |         7 | 
             |     0.286 |     0.429 |     0.143 |     0.143 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```